# Java system class in Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am using java methods in PL/SQL and recently I have stumbled upon this error :

> An error was encounterd performing the request operation:
>
> ORA-29548: Release of Java system classes in database (12.1.0.2.171017
> 1.6) does not match that of the oracle executable (12.1.0.2.180116 1.6)
> 29548. 00000 = "Java system class reported" %s"

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Has your DBA recently applied a patch or PSU?

Comment: That is possbile although I am not responsible for server.

Comment: Well you need to talk to your DBA. Almost certainly this is a configuration problem not a programming. If so, your DBA will need to run a post-install script or something.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the java version you use to compile and the version installed in ORACLE both are same.

```
select dbms_java.get_ojvm_property ('java.version')
from dual
```

Although, you can let Oracle do compile the source code directly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Azam/Azam_Test" as package Azam;

import java.lang.*;
public class Azam_Test {

    public static String Azam_Test_Print(String testString) {
      System.out.println(testString);
      return testString;
    }

}
```

Comment: But using this first query you gave me is throwing exactly the same error

Comment: this is the JDK version installed inside Oracle. either you have to upgrade the JDK version of Oracle to your JDK version OR you have to use the same JDK version of Oracle.
OR you may - let oracle compile the source code.

Comment: Ok, it turned out that there was a problem while patching database and nobody have noticed it

Comment: use below Create or Replace block. Oracle will compile the code and store both .java & .class file.
--------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Test_Name" as
**... JAVA CODE ...**